# Which is the first build comand to be used after a fresh installation of VS2005 and platform builder

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I have installed VS2005
Then PB with all R1 and R2 and other releases.

Now I create a new OS project select one of the bsp default installed.
Set it to release build

Next what....

From Build menu what to select.

Please note this is first build of any os on this PC.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/06/06/platform-builder-summary-of-building-windows-ce.aspx is a good reference point but no pointer found here for my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SYSGEN is the next step.

Comment: Did the same but fails on 
makefile.def: Including C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\misc\sources.ReleaseType_OAK
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\WINCE600\OSDesigns\SomeOS\SomeOS\Wince600\SomeBoard_ARMV4I\cesysgen\oak\lib\ARMV4I\retail\atls.lib'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\WINCE600\sdk\bin\i386\nmake.exe' : return code '0x2'

Vendor says you public folders might not yet built. Not getting what he mean to say.

Comment: You didn't do a "Clean and SYSGEN" did you?  That is a bad thing.

Comment: @Sachin: The exact name of the bad thing ctacke refers to is `build and SysGen` or `clean build and sysgen`. `Clean sysgen` is ok.

Comment: Solved. I am bit new to PB. I had selected something on directx and direct draw was no selected by default.